# Sorting by SortBy without converting to numerical values

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

First output returned by `Sort` is correct - ordered from smaller to bigger numbers.

Second output returned by `SortBy` is correct but only in the sense if `FullForm`'s are sorted, not values.

Third output returned by `SortBy` is correct - ordered from smaller to bigger number (because `N` was added in the code).

Fourth output return by `SortBy` is incorrect - we would need to add more decimal digits like with `N[,100]`.

```
Sort[{-2, -(2^20 + 1)^(1/20)}, Less]
SortBy[{{-2, 2}, {-(2^20 + 1)^(1/20), 2}}, {#[[2]], #[[1]]} &]
SortBy[{{-2, 2}, {-(2^20 + 1)^(1/20), 2}}, N@{#[[2]], #[[1]]} &]
SortBy[{{-2, 2}, {-(2^50 + 1)^(1/50), 2}}, N@{#[[2]], #[[1]]} &]

(* {-1048577^(1/20),-2} *)
(* {{-2,2},{-1048577^(1/20),2}} *)
(* {{-1048577^(1/20),2},{-2,2}} *)
(* {{-2,2},{-5^(3/50) 9007199254741^(1/50),2}} *)
```

But now I want to use `SortBy` the same way like `Sort` - without converting to numerical values. How to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the three-argument-form of `SortBy` with [`NumericalOrder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericalOrder.html):

```
SortBy[{{-2, 2}, {-(2^20 + 1)^(1/20), 2}}, {#[[2]], #[[1]]} &, NumericalOrder]
(* {{-2,2},{-1048577^(1/20),2}} *)
```

Comment: If I recall correctly there was no third argument in older versions.